# Pandas - Iteraction between 2 DFs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm dealing with a problem where I have a Dataframe that represents Purchase Orders by product, qty and price and, based on that, I need to generate a New Dataframe where I need to alocate, ordering by lowest price some quantities of the product to a Client.
So,

```
df1

   #PO Order Product  Qty  Price
0          1   Book1    5      3
1          2   Book1   15      4
2          3   Book1   20      5
```

Step 1: I need to alocate 15 Qtys of book 1, to client 1 selecting the ones with the lowest price possible, so `df2` sholud be:

```
     Client  #PO Order Product  Qty  Price
0  Client_1          1  Book 1    5      3
1  Client_1          2  Book 1   10      4
```

Step 2: And, by consequence I need to update df1, in order to update PO Order 1 and 2, by adding a column `'Updated_Qty'`:

```
   #PO Order Product  Qty  Price  Updated_Qty
0          1   Book1    5      3            0
1          2   Book1   15      4            5
2          3   Book1   20      5           20
```

Could you please help me to clarify How can I automate this iteraction of checking how much qty I need, selecting the correct PO and then update `df1`? I could accomplish this by a sequences of If Else, but seems to be very inefficient.

---

#### sample data construction

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    '#PO Order': [1, 2, 3],
    'Product': ['Book1', 'Book1', 'Book1'],
    'Qty': [5, 15, 20],
    'Price': [3, 4, 5]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Client': ['Client_1', 'Client_1'],
    '#PO Order': [1, 2],
    'Product': ['Book 1', 'Book 1'],
    'Qty': [5, 10],
    'Price': [3, 4]
})

df1_updated = pd.DataFrame({
    '#PO Order': [1, 2, 3],
    'Product': ['Book1', 'Book1', 'Book1'],
    'Qty': [5, 15, 20],
    'Price': [3, 4, 5],
    'Updated_Qty': [0, 5, 20]
})
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad!!!! I intended to say 15 as I allocated in DF2.

Comment: I edited your post to put it into a form that we prefer.  Hope you don't mind, it should help.

Comment: Thanks for help me! I think I do found a solution, I'll sort the df1 by price, and then make a cumulative sum column. Think this will make things easier